# Reliable java library for serial communication

Tags: java, serial-port

I am currently looking for a java library for serial communication, like txrx (which from what I understood isn't anymore updated) and that isn't too hard to use, as I need to implement it in a project which relies for 99% on the serial communication
I had the possibility to use Processing, which has an integrated library for serial communication, but I wanted to develop everything not over processing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use PureJavaComm for that purpose. Works also over USB-serial converters.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [protobuf](https://code.google.com/p/protobuf/) suits your needs?

Protocol Buffers are a way of encoding structured data in an efficient yet extensible format. Google uses Protocol Buffers for almost all of its internal RPC protocols and file formats.

Comment: Probably I wasn't very clear about what I needed, because the data I have to output must go from the computer through USB to a Usb-serial converter. The informations need to go in fact to an ATMEGA processor. Does the library you gave me do this type of things? If so, how can I use it to send a message in bytes at a specific baud rate?

Comment: No, protobuf is not tailored for such a conversion.